# Writing a bash script to copy all files between user specified directories!

Tags: bash

I need a shell (bash) script that can copy all files from one directory to another; where the source and target will be specified by the user calling the script.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You can do this in so many ways, post your script and any problem or questions you have.

Comment: AskUbuntu is not exactly the place to ask for someone to do your homework.

Comment: A friendly suggestion - always google your problem first before posting it here.  You will be surprised how many solutions you can find from googling.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think why you'd need a script for this.

```
cp /path/to/sourcedir/* /path/to/target
```

If you don't want to over-write files that have the same name in the source and target directories, use the `-n` or `--no-clobber` option.

```
cp -n /path/to/sourcedir/* /path/to/target
```

If you want to include hidden files (i.e. those beginning with a dot), use

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

before executing the `cp` command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little script...

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "..:: Script to copy source files/directories to another target location ::.."
echo "Supply the source file/directory below:"
read srcName
echo "Supply the target directory below:"
read dstName
echo " "
echo "..::  Copying from: Source -> Destination  ::.."
cp -rv -t "$dstName" "$srcName"
```

Comment: I'm a little noob on bash, but aren't you supposed to "declare" srcName and dstName before ? If not, why ? Thank you !

Comment: I'm no expert either.. never declared variables in bash.. this little [intro. to bash programming](http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) mentions that you don't have to declare since they don't have a data-type so that you can directly use them in script when and where needed.. _(a link to the official [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf))_...

Comment: @MrVaykadji: ..but this one shows the control you can get over your variables using *declare/typeset* ["Typing variables: declare or typeset"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html)

Answer (score 0):

i tried it and it work

```
find /path/to/A -name '*.deb' -exec cp -t /location/you/choose/ {} +
```

change the path and the location  (change .deb to ur file extension)

Comment: what does this {} + represents ??