# how to pass array into function and updates to array are reflected outsite function

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to pass a array into a function and whatever changes made to the array is reflected outside the function

```
function update_array()
{   
    ${1[0]}="abc" # trying to change zero-index array to "abc" , 
                  #  bad substitution error


}

foo=(foo bar)

update_array foo[@]

for i in ${foo[@]}
    do
       echo "$i" # currently changes are not reflected outside the function

    done
```

My questions are

1) How do i access the index array eg: zero index array , in the function , what is the syntax for it

2) How do i make changes to this index array so that the changes are reflected outsite the function also

Answer (score 3):

Several problems, in logical order of fixing:

- Style (pet peeve)
- With your `${...}` statement in `update_array()`, the `${..}` syntax to **use** a variable, not define it.

  Example:

  ```
  foo[0]=abc  # assigns 'abc' to foo[0]
  ```
- Working around that the array name is stored in a variable.

  Not working:

  ```
  $1[0]=abc
  ```

  Working:

  ```
  declare -g "$1[0]=abc"  # -g arg is for a global variable
  ```
- Passing an argument to `update_array()` should pass the variable name (`foo` in this case), not the contents of the array. `foo[@]` is nothing special, it is a completely normal string (in Bash).
- Variable expansion with `${foo[@]}` should be double-quoted.

Working version of the code is below:

```
update_array() {   
    declare -g "$1[0]=abc"
}

foo=(foo bar)

update_array foo

for i in "${foo[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done

## Following line added by me for further clarification
declare -p foo
```

which prints, correctly:

```
abc
bar
declare -a foo='([0]="abc" [1]="bar")'
```

Comment: that declaration's been confusing me.. shouldn't a declaration of variable precede the definition..

Comment: @hash `declare` is a bash builtin command (`help declare`). It is basically the same as variable assignment, `declare -g "$1[0]=abc"` is saying 'declare zero index of `$1` to be `abc`' (equiv. to (in theory) `$1[0]=abc`)

Comment: got that.. [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html) suggests, _"...`declare`/`typeset` are very weak form of the typing..."_ and may be I'll be using those only if I need to typecast my variables or other extra control..

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of variables might not be necessary in Bash.<sup>[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400082/writing-a-bash-script-to-copy-all-files-between-user-specified-directories/400133#400133)</sup> Yes you can use [`declare`/`typeset`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html) for more control over your bash variables. So I reckon you don't have to create a function just for the purpose of declaring a new array.

*This script below demonstrates a direct defining of array:*

```
#!/bin/bash
function define_array_elements() {
# You can note the array elements being defined directly, without a prior 
# definition of the variable.
for i in {1..10}; do
    var_name[$i]="Field $i of the list"
done
}

define_array_elements > /dev/null

for i in {1..10}; do
    echo "Field $i is: ${var_name[$i]}"
done
```

*(An example borrowed from [How to declare an array but not define it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402610/declare-an-array-but-not-define-it/402611#402611) with just a little modification.)*

Comment: Which version of bash does this apply to?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: you cannot. Bash does not have a way to pass variables by reference, so there's no generic way of doing it; you're left with (ugly) hacks including indirection and/or eval.

The upcoming bash 4.3 will introduce nameref variables, which allow you to pass variables by reference, but even this feature falls short since you still risk name collition.

```
# example of passing variables by reference in bash 4.3
update_array() {
    declare -n array=$1
    array[0]=abc
}

foo=( foo bar )

update_array foo

printf '<%s>\n' "${foo[@]}" # outputs <abc> and <bar>
```

In that example, if the array was named `array` instead of `foo`, it would fail since `declare -n array=array` is an error (`declare: array: nameref variable self references not allowed`).

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 for other hacks.